# Python TPL dataflow analog

Tags: python, task-parallel-library, dataflow

Is there an analogue of the .NET TPL Dataflow in the python world?

> Dataflow is a library where you can connect “blocks” to each in order to create a pipeline (or graph). There are different types of blocks that provide different functionality and that can operate concurrently. https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2019/05/15/tpl-dataflow-in-net-core-in-depth-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the Python, you can use the asyncio module for asynchronous programming, and libraries like asyncio.Queue or aioprocessing to achieve similar functionality to .NET TPL Dataflow. It might not be a direct match, but these tools allow you to handle concurrent and parallel tasks effectively.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of frameworks for that, both free and commercial.

The big ones would be
[Dagster](https://pypi.org/project/dagster) and
[Airflow](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow).
They focus on scheduling tasks in parallel where feasible,
and then bringing the results together for final tasks
that collect them all near the end of the
[task graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).
[Dask](https://pypi.org/project/dask) is another entry in this space.